# Copying files to other virtual machines using UNIX BASH

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need help with copying files from directory if they are not empty to other virtual machines using UNIX BASH (kinda new with it). 
e.g. VM ip 10.123.123.1 ; file name " q.txt". How do I make it ?

Comment: `scp` is generally a good tool for copying files around over SSH.

Comment: @vcsjones need to do it using script . To  be exact to implement this function to existing script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following script to check if the file is not empty and copy (`scp`) to your destination

```
_file="$1"
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 filename"; exit 1; }
[ ! -f "$_file" ] && { echo "Error: $0 file not found."; exit 2; }

if [ -s "$_file" ]
then
    echo "$_file has some data."
    scp $_file <USER>@10.123.123.1:<YOUR_DESTINATION_PATH>
else
    echo "$_file is empty."
fi
```

NOTE: You need to set the user name and path where you want to store your file on your destination target

Comment: Had a little bit to change but it worked. Thanks !